# Storing serialized objects into sdcard as file causing FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, serialization, filenotfoundexception, objectoutputstream

I want to serialize an object and store it inside `sdcard` under my project name but I'm getting `FileNotFoundException`.

My code is written below:

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = null;

File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), FILE_LOCATION + username);

try {
    if(!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    File file = new File(dir, FILE_NAME);
    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(formList);
    objectOutputStream.close();
} catch(IOException ioException) {
    ioException.getMessage();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.getMessage();
}
```

What is the reason for this issue? 
I'm running in emulator and my application is in android 3.0.

Comment: Have you added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> to your manifest?

Comment: I am having error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Cache/mathew/empInfo.ser (Is a directory) at line  fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

Comment: Try this File file = new File(dir, "test.txt"); instead of File file = new File(dir, FILE_NAME);

Comment: My filename had extension .ser, thats why I got exception. If I give txt its working fine.

Comment: Just tried this code, it works fine, so you are probably passing invalid values somewhere in those filename/file_location/object variables. I would check if mkdirs is actually returning true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your filename is invalid, maybe that . in the directory? Or the file-name its self.

Comment: filename had extension .ser which created problem for me.

Comment: Just a note, i tried with .ser extension and it seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but don't you have to create the File before you write to it?

```
File file = new File(dir, FILE_NAME);
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
}
```

Comment: Added this line...But still I am having error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Cache/mathew/empInfo.ser (Is a directory)

Comment: my guess is you created a dir earlier, which name was this of the file now. Try deleting /mnt/sdcard/Cache/mathew/empInfo.ser and then rerun your corrected code

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my solution for this since I got a lot of help from Stackoverflow on this issue (by searching for previous answers). My solution resulted for a couple of hours of searching and piecing together solutions. I hope it helps someone.

This will write and read an ArrayList of custom objects to and from External Storage.

I have a class that provides IO to my activities and other classes. Alarm is my custom class.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static ArrayList<Alarm> restoreAlarmsFromSDCard(String fileName,
        Context context) {

FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

ArrayList<Alarm> alarmList = new ArrayList<Alarm>();//Alarm is my custom class
//Check if External storage is mounted
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() != null) {
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "YourAppName/DesiredDirectory");

try {
if (!dir.exists()) {
Log.v("FileIOService", "No Such Directory Exists");
}
File file = new File(dir, fileName);
fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
alarmList = (ArrayList<Alarm>) ois.readObject();
ois.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
} else {
//Do something here to warn user
}

return alarmList;
}

public static void saveAlarmsToSDCard(String fileName, ArrayList<Alarm>     alarmList,Context context) {
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = null;

if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() != null) {
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "YourAppName/DesiredDirectory");

try {
if (!dir.exists()) {
dir.mkdirs();
}
File file = new File(dir, fileName);
fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
objectOutputStream.writeObject(alarmList);
objectOutputStream.close();
} catch (IOException ioException) {
ioException.getMessage();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.getMessage();
}
}else{
//Do something to warn user that operation did not succeed
}

}
```